# Creating & Using Correct Google OAuth 2.0 Key for Android IAP & Game Services

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-client, google-developers-console

I'm having some trouble getting the clientId to configure correctly for use of IAP and Google Play Games leaderboards & achievements in a game I'm ready to launch.

If someone here has experience working with Google Developer Console, and has roped this problem, please be a friend!

I've got the game to login to Google Play Services, but I accidentally deleted that keytool, now using another, but won't login or show achievements.  I may have to pay an expert. Let me know if that is you.

[image: not sure if I need BILLING permission]

Comment: Are there any error logs stating why you can't login or show achievements?

Comment: I'm unable to view the logs of an app downloaded from the App Store or Google Play at this time.  Instead, I've managed a workaround by replacing object function calls, ie, `store.saveHighScore()` with regular function calls: `saveHighScore()`. Thank you.